# Is there a tool for seeing audit events as they happen without writing them to the disk?

Tags: linux, audit

Linux has an audit system that is usually used together with auditd, a daemon that, as far as I know, is designed for logging all events to the disk. However, I would like a way to directly get the events as output of a command. Is there a command that attaches to the kernel the same way auditd does, but then just prints the audit events to stdout or so instead of writing them to a file?

Comment: Writing to a file is typically far more efficient writing to a terminal. You can control how much audit history is retained in auditd.conf and view the log files with `tail -f`. Is this not suited to your purpose?

Comment: @msw: I could do that... it just seems superfluous to write this stuff into a file... but if I don't find anything else, I'll do that, I think.

Comment: I have no idea what you are auditing, but some fundamental force of the universe will ensure that whatever you are interested in will happen when you stop looking. Also, disk is really cheap.

Comment: @msw: My usecase is "which folders need to be on my SSD so that my harddisk can spin down for extended time periods", so harddisk writes are not that cheap in my usecase :D – but if I need to use auditd, I could just put the audit log on a tmpfs.

Comment: You definitely want to write this stuff to a file. It's kind of hard to do a `ausearch` or an `aureport` on terminal data. If you do the tmpfs idea, make sure you limit the FS size otherwise you could easily get DoS'd.